# React Native Router Styling Issue Login Form Fields Stacking Up IOS Simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a `LoginForm` component which if used without `react-native-flux` appears normal as depicted in image below.

[image: LoginForm Component ios Simulator]

However if the same component is displayed through `Router` and `Scene` components of `react-native-router-flux` then all the fields stackup as depicted below.

[image: LoginForm Component through Router and Scene ios Simulator]

Below is the code of my `Router.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router, Stack } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

const RouterComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Router sceneStyle={{ paddingTop: 65, marginTop: 20 }}>
            <Stack key="root">
                <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" />
            </Stack>    
        </Router>
        );
};

export default RouterComponent;
```

`LoginForm.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input, Spinner } from './common';
import { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser } from '../actions';

class LoginForm extends Component {

    onEmailChange(text) {
        this.props.emailChanged(text);
    }

    onPasswordChange(text) {
        this.props.passwordChanged(text);
    }

    onButtonPress() {
        const { email, password } = this.props;

        this.props.loginUser({ email, password });
    }

    onLoginSuccess() {
        this.setState({
            email: '',
            password: '',
            loading: false,
            error: ''
        });
    }

    onLoginFail() {
        this.setState({ 
            error: 'Authentication Failed.',
            loading: false
        }); 
    }

    renderButton() {
        if(this.props.loading) {
            return <Spinner size="large" />;
        }
        return (
            <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
                        Log In
            </Button>
            );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input 
                        placeholder="example@example.com"
                        label="Email"
                        value={this.props.email}
                        onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
                    />
                </CardSection>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input
                        secureTextEntry 
                        placeholder="password"
                        label="Password"
                        value={this.props.password}
                        onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
                    />
                </CardSection>
                <Text style={styles.errorStyle}>
                    {this.props.error}
                </Text>
                <CardSection>
                    {this.renderButton()}
                </CardSection>
            </Card>
            );
    }
}

const styles = {
    errorStyle: {
        fontSize: 20,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: 'red'
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
    const { email, password, error, loading } = auth;
    return { email, password, error, loading };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser })(LoginForm);
```

Here are the styles applied to `Input`

```
const styles = {
    inputStyle: {
        color: '#000',
        paddingRight: 5,
        paddingLeft: 5,
        fontSize: 18,
        lineHeight: 23,
        flex: 2
    },
    labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 18,
        paddingLeft: 20,
        flex: 1
    },
    containerStyle: {
        height: 40,
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
}
```

Here is the style applied to `CardSection`

```
const styles = {
    containerStyle: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderColor: '#ddd',
        position: 'relative'
    }
};
```

Here is the style applied to 'Card`

```
const styles={
    containerStyle: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 2,
        borderColor: '#ddd',
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 2,
        elevation: 1,
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        marginTop: 10
    }
};
```

I have tried various methods but of no use. I appreaciate your help to sort out this issue.

Comment: this is related to component styling. Please show your code from `LoginForm` component for a better answer.

Comment: @bennygenel Updated the question to include the requested code. Please refer now.

Comment: can you try adding `flex: 1` to `Card` component style please

Comment: @bennygenel I have added `flex: 1` but the problem persist

Comment: One last suggestion. Wrap Card component with a View and add that a flex: 1

Comment: @bennygenel Nope the problem persists. Actually the problem is that the `CardSection` is not expanding based on child components height. If I manually set the height of `CardSection` then I get a proper display.